# How do you do vehicle rendezvous?

Tags: physics, vehicle

If you want to have a missile track and hit a target, [Proportional Navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_navigation) is a common technique.

But that's simple intercept and collision, getting the pursuer to the same X, Y, Z as the target.

But how about when you want to rendezvous with the target? Two vehicles with arbitrary vectors, the target on a stable (i.e. not trying to evade, but not necessarily straight) course, what techniques are folks using directing the pursuer to match the position, velocity, and heading of the target?

I think this is a different problem from station keeping or flocking (where the two vehicle are already close), but maybe not.

Comment: You may be interested in "[How can I maneuver an AI pirate ship for a sea battle?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/162030/39518)" which discusses a version of this problem for ships on a 2D ocean plane.