# Rear Propulsion Steering Spline, or what is this called?

Tags: vector, splines

What I am looking for is essentially to know what this is, or what I can google to learn how to do it... unless of course the solution is simple.[image]

You have an object at the start position facing a direction, and a desired position and direction.

The object has:

- max speed
- rotation rate
- acceleration
- deceleration

I am essentially trying to simulate the object having a "thruster" force acting on it.

[image]

I would like a smooth path from VecStart to VecEnd, where the object accelerates from stationary, and then decelerates as it gets to its desired position and rotation.

I am at a loss for what this is called, and where I should begin to research.

Comment: An exact/optimal solution to the problem you pose is in the domain of [Control Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory), and so far I've found it a bit too cumbersome to tackle precisely that way. (An engineer may do better here than a lowly game designer like me. ) But I do have a couple of previous answers looking at ways we can get decent solutions by thinking of our path as a Bézier spline. [Quadradic for constant thrust](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/75152/39518), or [cubic for linearly changing thrust](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/162038/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory Wow, this is a great response. Thank you Douglas. Cubic bezier looks to me like the easiest way forward.